# PyCharm - IdeaVim - "sneak" plugin : how to remap 's'?

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

I'm using PyCharm 2020.3.3 on Windows, with IdeaVim 0.64 and IdeaVim-Sneak" v 1.1.1 : https://github.com/Mishkun/ideavim-sneak

The default key for sneak is 's' but I'd like to change that mapping (let's say Alt + s).

I tried something this and some variants, but to no avail :
`nnoremap <a-s> <Plug>Sneak_s`

Does anyone know how to perform that remap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the plugin's creator answered in this issue : https://github.com/Mishkun/ideavim-sneak/issues/15

Use `nmap <a-s> <Plug>(sneak-s)` To map Alt+s

`nnoremap` doesn't work, at least for me. It has to be `nmap`. That specific point turned out to be the crux of the problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can use mappings to `<Plug>(sneak-s)`.

Comment: I was tempted to mark your answer as the solution, but it turns out that most of the problem was using `nnoremap` and not `nmap`. However you're right, that is the correct syntax for the end of the remap command.

Answer (score 1):

here is my setting,it works.

```
unmap s
nmap f <Plug>(sneak-s)
```